# SSL certificate update algorithm

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, mqtt, iot

I have an IoT device and an Android application. Both of them communicate with each other via an MQTT server, and this communication is encrypted by SSL. Based on my understanding, for security reasons, I need to renew the MQTT server certificate. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What is the common way to update the IoT device and Android application with the new certificate? Is it good practice to create a web service that provides the certificate from a database after the Android app and IoT device log into this server? Do MQTT server providers offer such a feature?

Comment: Typically you only need to renew the SSL cert on a server right before it expires, and if the cert is signed by a trusted authority then the clients (e.g. your Android app & your IoT device) don't need to be updated at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you are intending to using just server/broker side TLS or mutual TLS.

Assuming just server/broker side TLS then you have multiple choices

1. You use a broker certificate issued by a public trusted CA and you rely on the Android OS to provide the list of trusted CA certificates to verify the certificate. If you want a bit more security you also include the broker certificate's finger print in the application so somebody can't get certificate from another public CA with your brokers hostname (unlikely but possible for government level actors). If including the fingerprint then you will need to get replacement certs early and add the new fingerprint along side the old one to the application and publish an updated with enough time for users to update before the cert expires.
2. You use a certificate signed by your own private CA and bake the CA certificate into your application, if the CA certificate is going to expire, then you will need to again publish a new version of the application with enough time for users to upgrade.

If you are using a MQTT broker hosting provider, then they will most likely be using a public certificate CA, so you can only really do option 1 and most likely without fingerprinting as you won't have early access to the certificates used. The CA certs used to sign the broker cert will likely have expiry dates 10-50 years out, so should not need replacing in the life of the device.

If you are doing mutual TLS  authentication, then you need a way to create a signed certificate for every client, you should NOT reuse client certificate as that defeats the point of client certificates.

To do client certificates properly the client should generate it's own private key (and never share it with anybody else), then generate a Certificate Signing Request, which it sends to the CA to get signed, it then receives back a client certificate it can use with the private key to authenticate it's self. Every time this client certificate expires it should use the existing private key to generate a new CSR and get it signed by the CA again.

IoT systems like AWS IoT can offer client certificate provisioning iirc, but this is part of a much larger offering than just a MQTT broker.